# How to fix this Anagram Scrambler code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print "YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO REARRANGE YOUR THE WORD THAT YOU ARE ABOUT TO ENTER..."
word = raw_input ("FIRSTLY YOU MUST ENTER A WORD TO BE REARRANGED, ENTER IT HERE:")
character_save = word[1]
def anagram(word):

 if len(word)>1:

print str.replace('a','b')
word = str.replace(word[1],word[3])  
word= str.replace(word[3], character_save,1)
print word

anagram(word)
```

I tried to fix this on numerous occasions, the problem with the first time was that it would just replicate characters instead of replacing the positions, the second time I tried to store the position that I was going to replace in a variable but now it mentions that I have only one argument given (when it should be 2).

Would it be easier to do this with a list instead of a string?

Comment: You've misspelled your `charcter_save` variable.

Comment: I corrected the spelling error by the way but I'm still experiencing the same problem that I mentioned above (only one argument given).

Comment: I don't write Python, but isn't indentation important? It looks like you have a function definition, then the start of a conditional, and then the conditional and function ends there, since there is nothing in a greater indentation level. Does this compile?

Comment: Python strings support all the same sequence methods as do lists, so it'll be easiest for you to just keep this all as a string. In order to enable us to answer the rest of your questions, please fix the indentation on your posted code example and update your question to make it clear what exactly you want your code to be doing

Answer (score 0):

The replace message that you are using is called on the string that you want to replace and not on the `str` type itself.

In your case that is the `word` parameter that you are providing.

So if you replace the instances of `str.replace` with `word.replace` your code will run. However, it doesn't create an anagram yet. The algorithm is still lacking.